# How to find indices/rows where a combination of columns are equal to columns another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, database

I have two dataframes. The first one is with multiple entries of the same values in rows and the other only has one row for each combination of columns. I want to get the indices/rows of the first dataframe where column A, B and C are *pairwise equal* in the two dataframes *and* where column D in the first dataframe is equal to n. Column A, B and C are a subset of all columns. I want to specify that only those columns have to be equal.
With those indices I want to change the value of column E (simply using df.loc[indices, 'E']='n'.

The first one is the one with multiple entries for same values. The original dataframe has date stamps so it doesn't have multiple completely identical rows.

```py
   A B C D E
0  a b c y y
1  a b c y y
2  b n m n y
3  b n m n y
4  b n m n y
5  t u j y y
6  t u j y y
7  t u j y y
8  e t y y y
9  e t y y y
```

The second one only has one row per entry and not column D and E and is a subset of the entries in the first dataframe.

```py
   A B C
0  a b c
1  b n m
2  t u j
```

In this example the desired output is the list of indices where all conditions are fulfilled.

```py
[2,3,4]
```

I've tried with merge, while that does give me the right rows, I don't get the right indices to be used to update the first dataframe. I've also tried MultiIndex on the three columns but then I'm missing the filter on column D.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to get the list of indexes is to merge the two dataframes, adding the index as a column to the first, and assigning `'n'` to the `D` column in the second so that only rows which match on `A`, `B` and `C` and have `'n'` in `D` will match. Then you can take the index column from the first as your result:

```py
indices = (df1
    .reset_index(names='index')
    .merge(df2.assign(D='n'), on=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])['index']
    .to_list())
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
[2, 3, 4]
```

Note that the `to_list()` is not strictly necessary, the following code will work without it.

You can then use the indices to set `E` to `'n'`:

```py
df1.loc[indices, 'E'] = 'n'
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D  E
0  a  b  c  y  y
1  a  b  c  y  y
2  b  n  m  n  n
3  b  n  m  n  n
4  b  n  m  n  n
5  t  u  j  y  y
6  t  u  j  y  y
7  t  u  j  y  y
8  e  t  y  y  y
9  e  t  y  y  y
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a very pretty solution. The first df I have is concatenated and has indices all over the place (previously I reset the index). Using this approach, the indices returned seem to the original, even though you reset the index on the second line. Can I omit .reset_index(names='index') as I already have a column called 'index' in the first df?

Comment: @ThomasHemmingLarsen sorry about the slow reply, it's been night-time here. The reason the `reset_index` does not affect your original df is that I'm not assigning the output  of it, just using it as an input to `merge`. The reason for doing the `reset_index` is effectively to generate a column which represents row numbers in the df, but this only works if your existing index is a numeric range starting at 0 (as with the sample data in the question). So you would need to do a `reset_index` on the df *before* executing this code, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: @ThomasHemmingLarsen If you already have a column called `index`, you would need to change `index` in this code to another name which does not already exist in your df

Comment: Thanks! I was confusing myself. Its working :)

Comment: @ThomasHemmingLarsen Good to hear. I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `df1` and `df2`, you can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
# are the common columns (A/B/C) also in df2?
m1 = df1.merge(df2.assign(mask=True), how='left')['mask'].fillna(False)
# or
import numpy as np
m1 = np.isin(df1[df2.columns], df2).all(1)

# is "D" a "n"?
m2 = df1['D'].eq('n')

# if both conditions are True, update E
df1.loc[m1&m2, 'E'] = 'n'
```

Output:

```
    A  B  C  D  E
0   a  b  c  y  y
1   a  b  c  y  y
2   b  n  m  n  n
3   b  n  m  n  n
4   b  n  m  n  n
5   t  u  j  y  y
6   t  u  j  y  y
7   t  u  j  y  y
8   e  t  y  y  y
9   e  t  y  y  y
10  e  t  y  n  y  # not updated
```

Target indices:

```
df1.index[m1&m2]
# Index([2, 3, 4], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: Thanks. As far as I can tell, that solution also includes rows where D is equal to n and the other columns are not equal.

Comment: @Thomas not it doesn't: `m1 & m2` checks that **both** conditions are fulfilled

Comment: I added an extra row to demonstrate that, see update

Comment: Thanks, yes. Not sure what happened on my end.

Comment: One thing, can I change m1 = np.isin(df1[df2.columns], df2).all(1) to only use a subset of columns in df2?

Comment: Of course: `cols = ['A', 'B'] ; m1 = np.isin(df1[cols], df2[cols]).all(1)`